# How confirmations works and why this value change

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, evm

I am new in Ethereum smart contracts programming i was reading but is no clear for me. How confirmations works (if i am writing bad concepts  please tell me i jus wana be better :3 ) I undestand that a confirmation is when your transaccion is included to a block but why this value can change?

So the next question is how to avoid front running if i have my own geth node what is the process? I add my transaccion an inmediatly mine to avoid it replicate to the block chain and the when it replicate the transaccion is going to be irreversible?

I aprecite all your comments thanks for reading me :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of confirmations is actually the number of blocks that were mined after the block your transaction was mined on.

So the more blocks in the blockchain after yours, the less likely your block would have an uncle (causing it to revert). That's why some exchanges wait for 16 confirmations on Ethereum, this decreases the likelihood of tx being undone to close to 0.

Hence why it's also called "confirmations". The more confirmations, the more reliable your tx is.

Comment: Thanks now I undestand that point.  So if i have my own geth node i can mine my own transaccion and then avoid the front run so in that case i know that the transaccion is ok i only need one cofirmation? Thank you very much for the response

Comment: No, you can't mine your own transactions. Your node transmits the tx to the network, one of the miners will mine it and you'll be exposed to a frontrun. You're welcome, feel free to accept this answer.

Comment: Ah ok i undestand now thanks  :)